# QGIS - Print composer - Atlas - Show information depending on Atlas id

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, expression

The classic way to display information depending on the ID of the Atlas is to create a rule based symbology on the different layers we want to control.

Like: `"ID" = @atlas_pagename` or: `"ID" = @atlas_featureid`

But, this solution lead to the disappearance of the symbols on the project (since the conditions are not met).

**Do you know another solution, only through the print composer, to filter the information I want to display ?**

For example, in my situation, I would like to remove the data located outside the green rectangle.
I want to avoid using the rule-based symbology in my project.

[image: Example]

Comment: Why not use "ID" IN (@atlas_pagename, 'Name_layer_projet')? I think it should works

Comment: The layer which contains the lines I want to hide when outside the green rectangle is named: 'HABITATS_LINE' ; the green rectangles are in the layer '[T]_STUDY_AREA'. I tried to add this expression (following your indications: "ID" IN (@atlas_pagename, 'HABITATS_LINE'). It didn't change anything.

Comment: Page name = id, Filter = "ID" IN (@atlas_pagename, 'HABITATS_LINE'). Maybe I'm not writing in in the right place.

Comment: I think this it is something I could specify in the option "Layers", (the expression next to "Lock layers"). Something like concat('HABITATS_LINE', '|', 'New_area_2008_HQ_modified'), but with a specification for "ID" IN (@atlas_pagename, 'HABITATS_LINE')

Comment: Do that in the "rule based symbology", as you mentioned it... not in the "Lock layers".

Comment: But I would like to avoid using "rule based symbology". I know how to make it work through rule base symbology, but it changes the visibility of my layers when I need to work on it.

Comment: In the "Lock layers" options, there is a way to chose which layer I want to display. (concat('[T]_STUDY_AREA', '|','HABITATS_LINE', '|', 'New_area_2016_HQ_modified')) ; but I would like to specify something like ('[T]_STUDY_AREA',"ID") = @atlas_pagename and "ID" IN (@atlas_pagename, 'HABITATS_LINE'). But I have no idea on how to do this.